# Is there a way to use bokeh box annotation to highlight the same time frame each day?

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, pandas-bokeh

I have been unable to find any way to add a box annotation to a bokeh plot between the same set of hours for each day on a graph. For example, if I had a line graph of hourly data for an entire month, is it possible to add a box annotation between the hours of 5 and 10 each day without explicitly coding the left/right bounds of the box for each day in the dataset?

Does anyone know of any other solution in order to highlight on the graph the same time frame each day?

X-axis is in datetime format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Box annotations don't accept neither a data source nor an array of values.

You have 3 options:

1. Just as you said, explicitly specify the bounds
2. If it's possible, replace them with rect glyphs that accept data sources and/or arrays
3. Create a custom annotation class that renders multiple boxes